# canvas available in ms word 2016 (mac version)?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, shapes

For drawing in an MS Word for Mac 2016 document, a canvas is apparently no longer necessary.  Is it nevertheless available in any way?  I liked them; they helped keep things contained.

UPDATE: I am running on OS X.  Have been informed that it is rather different from Word on Windows machines.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Office 2016 handy current, seems like you can verify this easy enough, [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-drawing-to-a-document-348a8390-c32e-43d0-942c-b20ad11dea6f) is the help article on the subject.  `New Drawing Canvas.` will either exist or it won't.

Comment: Saw that.  It is explicitly for Office 2010.  Doesn't say anything, AFAICT, about changes in 2016.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: The location should be the same, if adding a Drawing Canvas is even possible, its should be here: "Within the Illustrations group, click on Shapes and then click New Drawing Canvas" if it isn't there then it was removed and you have your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Windows Word 2016, the option is called `New Canvas Drawing` and is at the bottom of Insert tab->Illustrations group->Shapes dropdown.

There is no such option on Mac Word 2016 (or 2011 for that matter). Word VBA on Mac does not currently have the AddCanvas command that the Windows version has, either, so it does not look as if you can create a macro to add one. (If you try to use the command to insert a shape of type msoCanvas, you get something that looks like a No Entry road sign, and it does not work like a canvas).

Because the canvas feature is not provided on Mac, it is difficult to recommend using them, as they may not actually be supported.

However, if you create a document on Windows Word and insert a canvas, then open that in Mac Word 2016 (or 2011), you get a Canvas that appears to work in a similar way on Mac. So if you have such a document, you could

- make a copy
- open it in Mac Word
- remove everything from the canvas and size/format it the way you want
- select the canvas and save it as an autotext

Then use the autotext feature to insert the canvas.

If you do not have such a document, you can use the XML I have provided below. To do that,

- Select all the XML and copy it to the clipboard (e.g. cmd-C on Mac)
- Open TextEdit and use File->New to create a blank document
- Paste the XML into that
- Use File->Save to save the document. I suggest that you select "Unicode UTF-8" in the "Plain text encoding" dropdown, uncheck "Hide Extension", and call the document canvas.xml. Make sure that TextEdit does not change the name (e.g. to canvas.txt or canvas.xml.txt)
- Use File->Close to close the document

You should then be able to open canvas.xml in Word. The canvas probably won't be visible until you click on it (it's at the top left of the document in the main text area).

Then save the canvas as an autotext, as suggested earlier.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part 
    pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" 
    pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" 
    pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship 
          Id="rId1" 
          Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" 
          Target="word/document.xml" />
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part 
    pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" 
    pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" 
    pkg:padding="256">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship 
          Id="rId1" 
          Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/settings" 
          Target="settings.xml" />
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part 
    pkg:name="/word/document.xml" 
    pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document 
        xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" 
        xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
        xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
        xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas">
        <w:body>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:drawing>
                <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="0" behindDoc="0" locked="0" layoutInCell="1" 
allowOverlap="1">
                  <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0" />
                  <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
                    <wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset>
                  </wp:positionH>
                  <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
                    <wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset>
                  </wp:positionV>
                  <wp:extent cx="4000000" cy="3000000" />
                  <wp:wrapNone />
                  <wp:docPr id="1" name="Canvas 1" />
                  <a:graphic>
                    <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas">
                      <wpc:wpc>
                        <wpc:bg />
                        <wpc:whole />
                      </wpc:wpc>
                    </a:graphicData>
                  </a:graphic>
                </wp:anchor>
              </w:drawing>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part 
    pkg:name="/word/settings.xml" 
    pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:settings xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
        <w:compat>
          <w:compatSetting w:name="compatibilityMode" w:uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word" w:val="15" />
        </w:compat>
      </w:settings>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
</pkg:package>
```

Comment: Wow!  Had no idea anyone was going to do that much work for this!  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much @user181946 This is one of the most generous and useful solutions I have been able to use. If I could I'd recommend you for an award. Why oh why did Microsoft not allow use to Insert a Canvas?! PS I secretly hope you work for Microsoft, perhaps even the Word for Mac team :-)

Answer (score 8):

I found a way to insert canvas like Microsoft Word (Windows version) using MAC by going to:

1. Open PREFERENCES
2. Open RIBBON & TOOLBAR
3. Dropdown menu for Command to ALL
4. Click ADD (+) in Customise ribbon (create new tab)
5. Select INSERT DRAWING from command ALL to the new tab

Comment: A better answer than xml copy + paste in my opinion.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the exact feature the OP and I were looking for and it functions the same as New Canvas Drawing does.

Comment: Nice!! I was about to give up, everyone says it's impossible on Mac. My God, it actually works very well!

Comment: Also worked for me, too. This answer really help Windows Word user like me adapting to using Word on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac You can insert a shape staright in word and then use tab 
"Shape Format" --> Arrange --> position --> "in line with text"

will give you the same effect as the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

The following should help:

> 1. Place the cursor roughly where you want the drawing canvas to be.
> 2. Go to the Insert tab.
> 3. Click the Shapes button and choose New Drawing Canvas.
>
> You can find **New Drawing Canvas** at the bottom of the
>   **Shapes** drop-down list.

Source: [How to Work with the Drawing Canvas in Word 2016 for Windows](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-work-with-the-drawing-canvas-in-word-2016.html)

### Please Note:

**This answer was written towards Office 2016 on Windows.**  When I originally submitted this answer, the question **made no mention of OS X**, so I wrote it towards the only version of Office I knew.  I am keeping this answer, since everyone else still find use out of it, but if people don't find it helpful I will just delete it.

Comment: If I think about it, I will go to the effort, of adding a screenshot later today.    Since the answer is complete, even without screenshots, it isn't actually a huge priority.

Comment: @Ramhoud and bibadia, thanks guys, but I'm sorry.  It just isn't there.  I'm on a Mac.  Is Word different on a Mac?

Comment: Yes; Office on OS X is entirely different.  You should have said that originally.  Great; I have to delete this answer, since it's completely useless, since Office on OS X has an entirely different feature set

Comment: That I did not know.  At all.  Will edit question.  Thanks.